# create stacked plot of percentages

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a dataframe containing the percentage of people in my dataset stratified per Gender and Age.

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Male','16-24',10],
                             ['Male','25-34',5],
                             ['Male','35-44',2],
                             ['Female','16-24',3],
                             ['Female','25-34',60],
                             ['Female','35-444',20],
                                ],
                        columns=['Gender','Age','Percentage'])
```

First I create a plot showig the percentages of Male and Female in the dataset

```
df_test.groupby('Gender').sum().plot(kind='bar',rot=45)
```

[image]

Now I would like to add within each bar the percentage of people in the age ranges in a stacked kind of way...
Could you help ?

Comment: Something like this -> https://pythonspot.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/stacked_bar.png ??

Comment: yes, with 3 stacks because there are 3 age ranges

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cumsum()` method for cumulative summation as

```
df_test.groupby('Age').sum().cumsum().plot(kind="bar",rot=45)
```